# Reduce gap between bars in Echart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, echarts

Is there a way to reduce gap between BARS in a bar chart made using Echarts. I tried the option `barCategoryGap` as mentioned in the docs but it had no effect.

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
        type: 'bar',
        barWidth: 50,
        barCategoryGap: '10%'
    }]
};
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: try to remove 'barWidth', and try to set 1% to see the difference

Comment: @Karl but I would like to control the bar width as well, removing it makes EChart control it. I don't want that mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `barGap`.

Documentation:
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barGap